# find the periodicity of a modular function

Tags: javascript, math

I created my own version of the fractal (which in fact takes the same principle as the Pythagorean tree).

If you want to know what this gives you can do a little tour here.

```
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById('cnv');
    var ctx =  myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    myCanvas.style.backgroundColor =  "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)";
```

My draw function like this.

```
  function draw(x, y, len, angle) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate((angle * Math.sin(len)) );
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -len);
    ctx.stroke();  
    ctx.strokeStyle = "grey";

    if(len < 1) {
      ctx.restore();
      return;
    }  
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRangeAngle");
    slider.oninput =  function() {
      var  p = document.getElementById('p');
      p.innerHTML = "L'angle : " + slider.value;
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1366, 900);      
      draw(550,578,120,0);
    }
   draw(0, -len, len*0.7, - slider.value);
   draw(0, -len, len*0.7, slider.value);
   ctx.restore();
  }

  draw(550,578,200,0);
```

https://codepen.io/m-metore/pen/Mxvqdq

Here is my problem I have an iterative function, U0 = 200; A + 1 = A * 0.7

or Un = U0 * 0.7 ^ n.

Then I multiply my angle x in (rad) by this formula:

f (x) = x * sin (Un).

My question is is there an integer x for which (fx) gives an integer.

In other words, we must solve x * sin (U0 * 0.7 ^ n) = 2 * PI; (where x and n are integers) and we look for x (which is an integer)
I specify that U0 = 200;

I do not think there is an x such that this equation is true. Do you have any idea of how to prove it?

thank you

Comment: This is more appropriate for [math.se]. But if both `U0` and `n` are known, you can compute the sine and you are left with `x * s = k * 2 pi`. Further `x = k * 2 pi / s`. If we substitute `2 * pi / s = c`, we want to find `k`, such that `k * c` is an integer. The easiest way to do is to try a few `k` (you probably don't want large `k` anyway).

Answer (score 0):

according to the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem sin (200 * O.7 ^ n) is a transcendent number https://planetmath.org/proofoflindemannweierstrasstheoremandthateandpiaretranscendental
so I have to show that arcsin (2 * PI / x) is an irrational number.

> The best way to do this is to try some k (anyway, you do not want big
>   k).

in fact I want to demonstrate for all numbers k that's why.
Thank you for your help !